# How to draw a 2D graph in Python - horizontal bars

Tags: python, graph

I would like to make graph like this in Python:
[image]

I have made the program in C that will give me combinations I need (here N=2n+|m| iirc), so could I integrate that here somehow?

I made something in Mathematica, but that's a pain in the butt... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Oh and I looked into matplotlib on examples if there could be anything, but nothing like this...

Comment: I doubt there's going to be a function to do that automatically, so you'll have to draw it yourself using `line()` style commands. http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#module-matplotlib.lines

Comment: so I just do basically the same thing as in Mathematica? :D I'll look into it ^^ Thnx

Answer (score 1):

I would customize CairoPlot for doing that (http://linil.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/cairoplot-11/ ) --
Cairoplot is a simple and small project to use the powerfull Cairo library to make Graph's. 
It does have few, although beauutiful, graphic options, but it is entirely made in Python - it should be possible to subclass a graph class from there to generate plots that fit your need.

Comment: I tried installing it in ubuntu as on the instructions but I got some error about Launchpad even tho I registered...

Answer (score 1):

You could try using step() in matplotlib

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html